# Can running a video over ethernet be split?

Tags: video, signal-processing

Running video over ethernet isn't something new, but is it possible to split the video signal (over short runs) without losing video signal - or at all?

I know you can buy these sort of items (just an example): http://www.aten.com/global/en/products/professional-audiovideo/video-extenders/ve800/ but if you were to run the ethernet into a switch, would the receiving end be able to be multiple Rx boxes?

I know this deviates from the normal ffmpeg question, but was curious if anyone had any proper insight into the way these boxes work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with those boxes, but the broadcast industry version of video over IP (SMPTE 2022-6 and the 2110 suite) can do this as they are actually IP Multicast based.

The gotcha is that they typically run uncompressed so you are looking at up to several Gb/s per multicast flow (4k60 you are looking at 12Gb/s), and you really want non blocking switching fabric.

It does work, but you will hate the price.

HDCP with consumer gear is also a bit of a pain (There are ways around that however).

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** Cat5 ≠ ethernet. Just because you're using the same cables as ethernet doesn't mean you're using the same protocols. The boxes you link to just boosts the HDMI signal so that it can go further down a copper wire without too much electrical interference, they don't turn it into TCP/IP packets that a router would understand.

You'd need a HDMI splitter with enough outputs, and then either more extender boxes or HDMI cable to go from the splitter to the TVs. Random example just to illustrate, not recommend [here](https://elbo.in/GzFb).